# apex:inputCheckbox isn't checked even though its value is "true"

Tags: visualforce, inputcheckboxes

On a Visualforce Page, `apex:inputCheckbox` isn't checked even though its `value` is `true`.

[image]

On both the Page and the Code, the `apex:inputCheckbox` is highlighted in **red**, and the value of the input is highlighted in **blue**.  Why are't the Checkboxes checked?  What could I be doing wrong?

I verified there is no JavaScript acting on the Checkboxes.

Upon inspection, the HTML says the `input`'s `checked="checked"`, but after adding `onmouseover="console.log('checked: ' + $(this).is(':checked'));"` to the `apex:inputCheckbox`, and the Console's log says

> checked: false

The Checkbox is definitely not checked.  And when I save the records without re-checking the Checkbox, the controller reads `isSelected` as `false`.

Answer (score 2):

I took off the `styleClass` on the `apex:inputCheckbox`, and they checked.

I'm using a VF Template, and the Parent had JavaScript that was unchecking the Checkboxes.